# How to find AWS EC2 with lowest latency to another server

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-ec2, network-programming, latency

I have a client sever located in AWS and I want to reduce latency between his machine and my EC2 instance. I rented two same servers in one availability zone and started sending requests to client`s API. It turned out that these servers have different latencies: 95-th percentiles were different for about 5 milliseconds (that is about 30% from mean latency). And my aim is to reduce latency.

I think that I can rent more servers and repeat these experiment, but it will be the next step of my investigation. The first step for me is to understand the reasons why servers in the same zone have so big difference in API response latency and which metrics can be useful to explain it?

The second way to reduce latency is to rent bare metal server instead of EC2, but it seems to be too expensive. And I am afraid that renting this server make even worse if it stand further from client server.

So, tell me please:

1. Do you have any advice how to reduce latency?
2. How can I rent closest server to my client in the same AWS zone?

Comment: availability zones are randomized. us-east-1a in account A could be different than account b's us-east-1a. The mapping is shown in the VPC section of AWS. The lowest latency setup uses [placement groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html), but I am not sure if they can work across accounts.

Comment: In addition to what jordanm said, your traffic is going to be going out to the Internet and back, which is going to cause all kinds of variable latency. Is it possible to setup VPC peering with your client?